# PDF Download and print options are not working in electron JS

Tags: javascript, electron

Download and print options are not working in elctron js.

Below are the code snippets that I tried:

Index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>    
    <h1>Electron Application </h1>
    <a href="Sample.pdf" target="_blank">PDF DOC</a> 
    
    <script>   
    </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Main.JS code:

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;



let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    
    maximizable:true,
    
    closable: true,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    frame: true,
    autoHideMenuBar: false, 
    kiosk: true,
    title: 'HR HUB',
    titleBarStyle:"default",
   
    webPreferences: {
     devTools: false
    }
  });
  
  
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

package.json code:

```js
{
  "name": "hrhub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
  }
}
```

Please find below download and print options screenshot. Download is not working and when I click on print and it pop up the print dialog box and I selected the Microsoft print to pdf and click on Print button and nothing happens. Please help on this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scStN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem with Electron 9.2.1 (the latest stable release as of today). Upgrading to 10.0.0-beta.25 solved it for me.

```
npm install -D electron@beta
```